# How can I eliminate column and row spacing in my Bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Inside the grid layout, the image just cannot cover the whole cell. Tried padding with the image, padding with the div section, and also the grid gap, they are all correctly set to 0px. I just want those weird padding to be gone(marked with blue).

The Bootstrap 5 .g-0 class does remove gutters between columns but does not remove gutters between rows.

The screenshot of my current webpage:

[image: the screenshot of my current webpage]

```css
.ai {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.algo {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid added-by-community">
  <div class="row added-by-community">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 algo bg-primary">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are padding,margin reset on figures ? are vertical-align or display reset on imgs ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't think there is a way to eliminate all the gutters, but use css to insert the background produces no gutter, just bypassing the problem.

Comment: I made a snippet from the code you left (and link BS css to it too) , it doesn't demonstrate your screenshot :( You can update the snippet to show what your issue is ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally don't like messing with a grid at a local level (only as a global override). Instead, use the grid as intended and modify the *content*, say with negative margins to negate the grid spacing.

Better, just don't use rows and columns. Use basic [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/). Here I'm extending Bootstrap's [sizing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent) with a custom class for 1/3 width above the `md` [breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints). I'm also using `m-0` on the figures to eliminate their bottom margin.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body .w-md-33 {
    width: calc(100% / 3) !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="w-50 w-md-33 algo bg-primary">
    <figure class="m-0">
      <img class="img-fluid ai" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" />
    </figure>
  </div>

</div>
```